# How can I write a scope to return all movies that are `not_voted_by` given user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails I have 3 models: `Movie`, `Vote` and `User`

```
class Movie
  has_many :votes
end

class User
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have a scope `voted_by` for model `Movie`, which returns all movies voted by given user.

```
class Movie
  scope :voted_by, ->(user) {
    includes(:votes).where(votes: { user: user })
  }
end
```

Now I want another scope `not_voted_by` which does exact the opposite: it should returns all movies that are **NOT** voted by given user.

How can I achieve that?

What I come up with so far is:

```
scope :not_voted_by, ->(user) {
  includes(:votes).where.not(votes: { user: user }).or(
    includes(:votes).where(votes: { user: nil })
  )
}
```

It works when a movie is voted by one or zero user.
But it doesn't work when the movie is voted by multiple users.

For example if movie `M` is voted by both user `A` and `B`. `Movie.not_voted_by(A)` still includes `M` while it shouldn't.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Includes in SQL means left join. So you add all records in the left where user not a `user`. SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN votes ON (votes.movie_id = movies.id)
WHERE votes.user_id <> 1
```

If you have e.g. in table.

```
id | movie_id | user_id
-----------------------
1  | 1        | 1
2  | 1        | 2
3  | 2        | 2
```

Then you query exclude only first record if `user.id = 1`.

So, I think you need to exclude voted movies by negate previous scope

```
scope :not_voted_by, ->(user) { where.not(id: voted_by(user) }
```